# Create a new dataframe by breaking down the columns data of an old dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below dataframe

| salesman | north_access | south_access | east_access | west_access |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| C | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

I want to convert the above into the below format

| salesman | direction | access |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | north | 1 |
| A | south | 0 |
| A | east | 0 |
| A | west | 1 |
| B | north | 0 |
| B | south | 1 |
| B | east | 1 |
| B | west | 1 |

I tried exploring the split and transpose function but didnt get the expected results.
Can someone please help with the code to make the above changes in python, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another solution (using [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html#pandas-wide-to-long)):

```py
df.columns = [f'access_{c.split("_")[0]}' if "_access" in c else c for c in df.columns]

x = pd.wide_to_long(
    df, stubnames="access", suffix=r".*", i=["salesman"], j="direction", sep="_"
).reset_index()
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   salesman direction  access
0         A     north       1
1         B     north       0
2         C     north       1
3         A     south       0
4         B     south       1
5         C     south       0
6         A      east       0
7         B      east       1
8         C      east       1
9         A      west       1
10        B      west       1
11        C      west       1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
>>> (df.set_index('salesman').rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_')[0])
       .rename_axis(columns='direction').stack().rename('access').reset_index())

   salesman direction  access
0         A     north       1
1         A     south       0
2         A      east       0
3         A      west       1
4         B     north       0
5         B     south       1
6         B      east       1
7         B      west       1
8         C     north       1
9         C     south       0
10        C      east       1
11        C      west       1
```

Or with `melt`:

```
>>> (df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_')[0])
       .melt('salesman', var_name='direction', value_name='access')
       .sort_values('salesman', kind='stable', ignore_index=True))

# OR

>>> (df.melt('salesman', var_name='direction', value_name='access')
       .sort_values('salesman', kind='stable', ignore_index=True)
       .assign(direction=lambda x: x['direction'].str.rstrip('_access')))

   salesman direction  access
0         A     north       1
1         A     south       0
2         A      east       0
3         A      west       1
4         B     north       0
5         B     south       1
6         B      east       1
7         B      west       1
8         C     north       1
9         C     south       0
10        C      east       1
11        C      west       1
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is with [janitor.pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.pivot_longer(index = 'salesman', 
                names_to = ('direction', '.value'), 
                names_sep = '_')
   salesman direction  access
0         A     north       1
1         B     north       0
2         C     north       1
3         A     south       0
4         B     south       1
5         C     south       0
6         A      east       0
7         B      east       1
8         C      east       1
9         A      west       1
10        B      west       1
11        C      west       1
```